# Launch Android emulator in landscape orientation

Tags: android, emulation, screen-orientation

Is there any way to tell Eclipse to launch the Android Emulator (4.1.2) in landscape mode?

My reason for asking is that changing the orientation (using one of the keyboard shortcuts) **after** starting the emulator does not seem to affect the home and other system screens, although it works fine with apps.

I am aware of the `-skin` command line option, but it has been deprecated.

I suppose that I could also create a custom device in Android Virtual Device Manager but I'd rather use the Nexus 7 preset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a new AVD using custom resolution.

Simply fire up the AVD manager, create new AVD, choose your target and tick the resolution and add a resolution fit for landscape, like 480 x 640.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid messing with custom AVDs but if all else fails, this is the answer I'm going to choose.

Comment: Admittedly not much of an answer but it is the only way I had any luck with this.

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
ctrl+fn+F11 in Mac to change the landscape to portrait and vice versa.

left-ctrl+F11 in Windows 7.

ctrl+F11 in Linux.
```

Comment: I know about the keyboard shortcut, but like I said, doing it that way doesn't affect the system screens.

Comment: @ed Auto-Rotation is on. Interestingly, launching in landscape using Tapirboy's approach and then changing to potrait works fine. The reverse, however, does not.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug when using the 4.4 emulator. You can rotate the emulator using the `ctrl+F11` shortcuts mentioned above, or using the `9` key on your keypad.

Once you have the emulator in landscape, open the camera app in the emulator, which will rearrange all the controls to where they should be in landscape mode. You can then launch your app from eclipse/android studio and it will properly appear in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new AVD you can use the current AVD you're using and just Edit it (from AVD manager) and then you can change the option of "Orientation" between Portrait and Landscape.